# Java Generic Inheritance / Generic Comparable

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Say that I have a function that does things with a list of shapes.  I can define a few useful classes:

```
public abstract class Shape implements Comparable<Shape> { }

public abstract class FourSidedShapes extends Shape { }

public class Rectangle extends FourSidedShapes{
   ...
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Shape o) {
    return 0;
   }
}

public class Square extends FourSidedShapes {... }
```

I have a helper container:

```
//Implements doubly-linked sorted list
public class SortedLinkedListNode<T extends Shape> {
   public SortedLinkedListNode<T> add(T e) { }
   public <E extends Shape> T get(E target) { }
   ...
}
```

I would like to do something like this:`TreeSet<FourSidedShapes> myshapes;`

If I do that, I have two problems.  First, I want to keep the SortedLinkedList helper collection as generic as possible.  So I would like to write the implementation assuming that it will hold Shape or some subclass of shape (including objects that have not been considered / implemented such as circles / triangles, etc.  But if I do that, then I have to implement public int compareTo(Shape o) for both rectangle and square even though I really only want to implement public int compareTo(FourSidedShapes o) because I'm really only storing subclasses of FourSidedShapes in my collection.  So my question is, how do I modify my SortedLinkedListNode so that it extends a compareTo that is no lower than the base class that it is storing?  For example, if I am storing shapes, then it expects shapes to implement `Comparable<Shapes>`.  If I'm storing FourSidedShapes, then it expects FourSidedShapes to implement `Comparable<FourSidedShapes>`.  I suspect that the right answer involves making the parameter of Comparable generic, but I'm not sure what that look like.  For example, something like

```
public class ShapeComparable<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   public abstract int compareTo(T other);
}
```

Comment: Your Shape classes should probably not implement Comparable at all, since their doesn't seem to be any clear natural ordring applying to all shapes. Instead, you should pass a Comparator to the TreeSet constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely clear on your question but I am assuming that you are asking how to make `Rectangle` or `FourSidedShapes` implement `Comparable<FourSidedShapes>`. 
Here is the code showing how to do that:

```
public abstract class Shape< T extends Shape<T> > implements Comparable<T> { }

public abstract class FourSidedShapes extends Shape<FourSidedShapes> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FourSidedShapes o) {
        return 0;
    }        
}

public class Rectangle extends FourSidedShapes{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FourSidedShapes o) {
        return 0;
    }

}

public class Square extends FourSidedShapes{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FourSidedShapes o) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```